# Why am I occasionally getting this error: database could not be selected

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This issue is appearing while trying to connect to a Wordpress website hosted on my local machine (localhost).
I am using the XAMPP application, which runs with php 8.2.0 and MariaDB 10.4.27, on windows 10.
XAMPP is apparently running well, with both apache and MySql up and running,

Sometimes I also get this message when trying to connect to my local website

> Could not select database
>
> The database server might be connected (which means your username and password are OK), but the wp_sinreg database could not be selected.
>
> Are you sure it exists?
> Does the user root_wordpress have permissions to use the wp_sinreg database?
> On some systems, your database name is prefixed with your username, so it would be something like username_wp_sinreg. Could that be the problem?
>
> If you don't know how to create a database, you should contact your host. If all else fails, you can find help on the WordPress support forums.

The database exists obviously and can be accessed through phpmyadmin and it is not prefixed with a username.

After looking at the MySql.err file, I can't spot any malfunctioning-related messages:

> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows
> interlocked functions   2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses
> event mutexes
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
> size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
> buffer
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from
> checkpoint LSN=1172954507
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments
> are active.
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data
> file: "ibtmp1"
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
> temporary tables
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
> 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
> file full; Please wait ...
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
> size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence
> number 1172954516; transaction id 434262
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
> D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at
> 230529 11:21:44
>
> 2023-05-29 11:21:44 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

As for the part of the message saying:

> Does the user root_wordpress have permissions to use the wp_sinreg
> database?

after trying to display the user accounts in PHPMyAdmin, I receive the following error (and no users are displayed!):

> phpMyAdmin configuration storage
>
> Configuration of pmadb… hasn't received OK (see Doc)
>
> General relationship options: Disabled
>
> Create a database called 'phpmyadmin' and configure phpMyAdmin
> configuration storage.

and ...

> Error
>
> consulta SQL: Copiar Documentación Editar Editar
>
> ```
> (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` ) UNION (SELECT
> DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
> `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
> `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
> `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv` ) ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host`
> ASC
> ```
>
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
> #1030 - Error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from Aria table handler

So although MySQL seems to be running fine, something is wrong ...
Can anyone help understand what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is some checksum error in the tables of the query.

Run:

```
REPAIR TABLE mysql.db, mysql.tables_priv, mysql.columns_priv, mysql.procs_priv, mysql.global_priv
```

`global_priv` is there as `mysql.user` is a view on the `global_priv` table.

ref; [REPAIR TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/repair-table/)

Comment: I am not sure if I have to run this command literally as is or substitute other items instad of the 'mysql.x' arguments (I have no experience with sql).
I tried to actually run it as is, and it seems to work except that it doesn't solve the problem, No users displayed

Comment: if I go to the mysql.user VISTA I can see that the (previously) existing users are still there

Comment: Check executing all components of the query like `SELECT DISTINCT
User,Host FROM `mysql.tables_priv` to see if they don't error. Try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after the repair, or restart the mariadb service.

Comment: After executing SELECT DISTINCTfor all components, "SELECT DISTINCT User,Host FROM mysql.colums_priv" fails, saying that 'mysql.colums_priv' doesn't exist when it actually does.
FLUSH PRIVILEGES causes: "#1030 - Error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" desde el manejador de la tabla Aria"

Comment: `colums_priv` has a typo that I just corrected. Re-repair (using the right `columns_priv` spelling). Hopefully that's the one with the checksum issues.

Comment: Ok yes, this seems to be the one with checksum problems:
#1030 - Error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" desde el manejador de la tabla Aria

Comment: Ok @danblack. Thanks for your support. Indeed that was the table with the wrong checksum. I repaired the table and can finally display my website